# Checking for state changes in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to detect if something has changed in a div. I have two divs, one for a heading and one for a message, i could just use normal input methods like textarea and input of text but i want the look of the site to be sleek and would rather they look like normal web page elements till a user clicks on them (I am also using CKEditor to do inline text editing).

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" class="editable-header">A Heading</h1>

<div class="update-text" contenteditable="true">
    A message
</div>
```

So i would like to be able to change the state of a button on when something has changed in one of those boxes using Jquery.

I have tried using

```
$(".editable-header").change( function(){
    console.log("Something has changed!");
 });
```

But this doesn't seem to fire, i also tried

```
$(".editable-header").on("change", function(){});
```

Change this be done with an editable div? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

`h1` is not input element so when the content change inside `h1` at that time You need to attach `event`, see sample code

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" class="editable-header">A Heading</h1>

<div class="update-text" contenteditable="true">
    A message
</div>
<input type="button" value="Change title"/>
```

And jQuery code

```
$(".editable-header").change( function(){
    alert("Something has changed!"); 
 });

$("input[type=button]").on('click', function(){
   $(".editable-header").text("Fooo").trigger("change");
   //OR $(".editable-header").text("Fooo").change();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cecsfsjg/)

**UPDATE** on comment, if `element` is contenteditable="true" then this code to work combine even change content by keyword or dynamically.

```
$(".editable-header").on('keyup change', function(){
    alert("Something has changed!"); 
 });
```

Comment: but `contenteditable="true"`makes h1 editable just like a text input. Just try to edit it in place - it will work.

Comment: no, it's `contenteditable`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable. And it's in question code actually, just in the beginning: <h1 **contenteditable="true"** class="editable-header">

Comment: you right :), lets take coffee more stress here, I didn't focus on that, updated section code will work when element have `contenteditable="true"` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use `input` event for this.

```
$(".editable-header").on("input", function(){console.log('edited')});
```

**Update**

`input` doesn't work in [IE10-11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/794285/ie10-11-input-event-does-not-fire-on-div-with-contenteditable-set), which is a reported bug. 
On contrary, `keyup` works in IE too.

```
$(".editable-header").keyup(callback);

function callback() {
    console.log('edited');
}
```

Note: using both events at the same time will cause callback to be executed twice in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur event....but you need to check it's text really changed

```
$(".editable-header").on("blur", function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
function OnEditableObjectChange(ClassName, Callback)
{
    var interval = 0;

    var elts = document.getElementsByClassName(ClassName);
    for(var i = 0; i < elts.length; ++i)
    {
        elts[i].addEventListener("focus", function(){
            var that = this;
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                Callback(that.innerHTML);
            }, 16);
        }, false);

        elts[i].addEventListener("blur", function(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, false);
    }
}

/* Exemple */
OnEditableObjectChange("editable-header", function(txt){
    document.getElementsByClassName("update-text")[0].innerHTML = txt;   
});
```

JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4quo0ho2/

---

Does it respond to your needs ? :)

(Sorry if my english is not really good, I'm french ^^)